# SQL Server remote connection error

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, remote-access, remote-server

I'm trying to make a remote connection to a SQL Server DB from my PC out of the office by a VB 2012 program.

First, I connect it with the internal IP and local host, now with the same program
I want to connect with the public IP.

I used the next string connection:

```
public SQLConn As New SqlConnection With 
{.ConnectionString = **"Data Source= PublicIP,1433\ServerName; InitialCatalog=DBName;Integrated Security=False;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx"}
```

but the following error appears:

> Login failed for user 'xxxx'.

Comment: login failed means `the user does not have permission to login or your are using incorrect credentials for user` also check if `SQL Server Authentication` is enabled.

Comment: check whether the port is opened, also the authentication credentials are correct

Comment: Port is open, credencials are ok. Permissons are all active. But the error persist.

Comment: not sure if a typo or not, but your connection string DataSource has the port inside, that needs to be at the end - `PublicIP\ServerName,1433`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try connecting to mysql -h "public ip"

Is that working?

If not, then you might have to open some ports or do some port forwarding to let the world access the mysql port.

Comment: it's mssql, not mysql and he can actually reach the server, but fails to authenticate.

Comment: that's it, i'm using SQL Server 2014 with the mssql and connection to server is ok,
But I have trouble when I try to connect by an external IP